# Smack 4.1 anonymous registration to Openfire

Tags: android, openfire, smack

I have tried enough but getting error when trying to register a user through smack 4.1 on openfire server without any login (anonymous). With a user login, the registration works fine.

I have already checked [Smack 4.1 Android anonymous registration to Openfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394635/smack-4-1-android-anonymous-registration-to-openfire) link but still getting the same error (Bad Request - Modify).

```
<iq type="error" id="R6rBt-3" from="192.168.0.105" to="desktop-ebr9dof/a96febd1"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:register"><username>user4</username><password>uhifg123</password></query><error code="400" type="modify"><bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

below is the code snippet I've applied in my code:

```
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
        configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        configBuilder.setServiceName("192.168.0.105");
        configBuilder.setHost("192.168.0.105");
        configBuilder.setPort(5222);
        configBuilder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
        configBuilder.setCompressionEnabled(false);
        configBuilder.setSendPresence(true);
        configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword("user4", "uhifg123");

    XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());

    try {
        connection.connect();
        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(connection);
        accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("username", "user4");
        map.put("password", "uhifg123");
        SASLAuthentication.unBlacklistSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
        SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5");
        try {
            accountManager.createAccount("user4", "uhifg123", map);
        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (SmackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```