# Android, Openfire, Smack, XMPP

Tags: android

I want to anonymous register new user into openfire using smack in android. I am using Smack 4.1.0 and Openfire 4.0.2. If I login with already register user and then try to register then it work perfectly. But I want to register without login with other account.

I have also referred [Smack 4.1 Android anonymous registration to Openfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394635/smack-4-1-android-anonymous-registration-to-openfire) but its also not working.

Connection Builder :

```
    Configure conf = new Configure();
    conf.configure(new ProviderManager());

    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration
            .builder();
    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    config.setServiceName(serverAddress);
    config.setHost(serverAddress);
    config.setPort(5222);
    config.setResource(context.getResources().getString(R.string.resource_name));
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    config.setSendPresence(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptiodDefault(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
    mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
    XMPPConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener(type);
    mConnection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);
```

User Registration :

```
public void createNewAccount() {
     AccountManager accountManager =AccountManager.getInstance(mConnection);
     if (accountManager != null) {
        Log.d("Account manager", "NOT NULL");
        accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
        Map<String, String> attr = new HashMap<String, String>();
        attr.put("username", loginUser);
        attr.put("password", passwordUser);
        attr.put("email", loginUser);
        try {
            accountManager.createAccount(loginUser, passwordUser, attr);
            accountCreated = true;
        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     } else {
          Log.d("Account manager", "NULL");
     }
}
```

and I got Bad Request Error.

```
 06-15 15:53:27.332 2026-10349/com.dsquare.dchat I/System.out: 03:53:27 PM SENT (0): <iq to='192.168.0.250' id='IAX28-1' type='set'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'><email>dharmesh1</email><password>dharmesh1</passwor d><username>dharmesh1</username></query></iq>
 06-15 15:53:27.364 2026-10350/com.dsquare.dchat I/System.out: 03:53:27 PM RECV (0): <iq type="error" id="IAX28-1" from="192.168.0.250" to="divyang-pc/9f351hyo93"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:register"><email>dharmesh1</email><password>dharmesh1</passwor d><username>dharmesh1</username></query><error code="400" type="modify"><bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
 06-15 15:53:27.440 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: bad-request - modify
 06-15 15:53:27.468 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:2 32)
 06-15 15:53:27.496 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:2 13)
 06-15 15:53:27.508 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.iqregister.AccountManager.createAccount(AccountManager. java:272)
 06-15 15:53:27.512 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err:     at com.dsquare.xmppservices.XMPPConnection$XMPPConnectionListener.connected(XMPPCo nnection.java:989)
 06-15 15:53:27.528 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.callConnectionConnectedListener(A bstractXMPPConnection.java:1152)
 06-15 15:53:27.532 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection. java:841)
 06-15 15:53:27.544 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.ja va:360)
 06-15 15:53:27.548 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err:     at com.dsquare.xmppservices.XMPPConnection$2.doInBackground(XMPPConnection.java:25 2)
 06-15 15:53:27.552 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err:     at com.dsquare.xmppservices.XMPPConnection$2.doInBackground(XMPPConnection.java:23 4)
 06-15 15:53:27.560 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 06-15 15:53:27.564 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
 06-15 15:53:27.568 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
 06-15 15:53:27.576 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
 06-15 15:53:27.580 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
 06-15 15:53:27.584 2026-10348/com.dsquare.dchat W/System.err:     at      java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check in the **Server Settings/Registration & Login** if you have the right permission to register accounts.

Also you can do:

```
accountManager.supportsAccountCreation()
```

to check if this option is available.

And please check the attributes that you send. I do not think you need to pass password and login again.

Answer (score 0):

Below is code without login create new user

```
public boolean registerUser(String mUserName, String mPassword, String mName, String mEmail) {

    // Now we create the account:
    Map<String, String> mUserInfo = new HashMap<>();
    mUserInfo.put("name", mUserName);
    mUserInfo.put("first", mName);
    mUserInfo.put("email", mEmail);
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(RoosterConnection.getConnection());
    accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
    try {
        Localpart username = null;
        try {
            username = JidCreate.bareFrom(mUserName+ "@" + Config.mServiceName).getLocalpartOrNull();//                accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(false);

        } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
            accountManager.createAccount(username, mPassword, mUserInfo);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "saveCredentialsAndLogin() called.");
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        prefs.edit()
                .putString("xmpp_jid", mUserName + "@" + Config.mServiceName)
                .putString("xmpp_password", mPassword)
                .putBoolean("xmpp_logged_in", true)
                .apply();//            RoosterConnection connection = new RoosterConnection(SignUpActivity.this);
        RoosterConnection connection = RoosterConnection.getInstance();
        connection.RoosterConnection(SignUpActivity.this);
        connection.login( mUserName + "@" + Config.mServiceName,mPassword,true);
        return true;
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error : "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
        return false;
    } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error : "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error : "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

After registration successfully, call login method and and you will get broadcast from server.

```
 mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case RoosterConnectionService.UI_AUTHENTICATED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got a broadcast to show the main app window");
                    //Show the main app window
                    // showProgress(false);
                    Intent i2 = new Intent(this, ContactListActivity.class);
                    i2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(i2);
                    finish();
                    break;
            }

        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(RoosterConnectionService.UI_AUTHENTICATED);
    this.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```